# spring batch job parameters in StepScope

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job (v4.3.1,no xml configuration) to load a CSV file in a database.
The jobs are started by a rest controller so not automatically at start.
It all works fine when the filename is known at startup of the application.

But when I try to pass a jobParameter to the step (and annotate it with @StepScope) I get an exception at the start of the application (at that moment the job is not started yet).
The exception I get is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.<init>(FileSystemResource.java:80) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at TaskImportJobConfiguration.importTasksReader(TaskImportJobConfiguration.java:66) ~[classes!/:na]
    at TaskImportJobConfiguration.step1(TaskImportJobConfiguration.java:109) ~[classes!/:na]
    at TaskImportJobConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b686b37a.CGLIB$step1$3(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at TaskImportJobConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b686b37a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7987bf2f.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar!/:5.3.2]
    at TaskImportJobConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b686b37a.step1(<generated>) ~[classes!/:na]
```

The step1() method calls `.reader(importTasksReader(null))`. This should work as the parameters are bound at runtime. But I notice this is not what is happening. At the moment the step1() method is called (so at startup of the application) the FileSystemResource passed to my ItemReader checks the parameter which is null at that time and thus throws an exception.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Here is my code:

```
import java.beans.PropertyEditor;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.PassThroughItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;

@Configuration
public class TaskImportJobConfiguration {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskImportJobConfiguration.class);
    
    private static final String QUERY_INSERT_TASK = "INSERT INTO TASK (N_I_IDF, C_I_TASK_CODE, C_TASK_TYPE_CODE) "
            + "VALUES (NEXTVAL FOR TASK_SEQ, concat('BC',varchar_format(NEXTVAL FOR TASK_SEQ,'000000000')), :taskType)";
    
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    public Job importTasksJob(Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importTasksJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1).end().build();
    }

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<CsvTask> importTasksReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['inputfile']}") String inputFile) {
        logger.info("IN-ImportTasksReader ("+inputFile+")");
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<CsvTask>()
                .name("taskItemReader")//
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(inputFile))//
                .linesToSkip(1)//
                .delimited()//
                .delimiter(";")
                .names(new String[] { "taskType"})
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<CsvTask>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(CsvTask.class);
                        // 8< some custom editors >8
                    }
                }).build();
    }
    

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<CsvTask> taskWriter(DataSource datasource, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<CsvTask> itemwriter=new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        itemwriter.setDataSource(datasource);
        itemwriter.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
        itemwriter.setSql(QUERY_INSERT_TASK);
        itemwriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
        return itemwriter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<CsvTask> taskWriter) {
        return stepBuilderFactory //
                .get("importTasksJob.step1")//
                .<CsvTask, CsvTask>chunk(10) //
                .reader(importTasksReader(null)) //
                .processor(new PassThroughItemProcessor<CsvTask>())
                .writer(taskWriter) //
                .build();
    }       
}
```

UPDATE: when I add @bean annotation to importTasksReader like :

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<CsvTask> importTasksReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['inputfile']}") String inputFile) {
```

I get following exception:

```
2021-02-15 15:10:06.531  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'scopedTarget.importTasksReader' defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [TaskImportJobConfiguration.class]: 
Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [TaskImportJobConfiguration.class]] for bean 'scopedTarget.importTasksReader': 
There is already [Root bean: class [null]; scope=step; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=taskImportJobConfiguration; factoryMethodName=importTasksReader; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [TaskImportJobConfiguration.class]] bound.
2021-02-15 15:10:06.577 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
 ***************************

 Description:
 The bean 'scopedTarget.importTasksReader', defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [TaskImportJobConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [TaskImportJobConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
 Action:
 Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

For completeness: my application @Configuration class also instantiates the StepScope:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public static StepScope scope() {
        return new StepScope();
    }
   // ... other stuff hidden here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your item reader is not declared as a bean, hence it is not proxied and created lazily when the step requests it. What happens with your current configuration is that the step calls a method with a `null` parameter.

You need to add `@Bean` in addition to `@StepScope`:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<CsvTask> importTasksReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['inputfile']}") String inputFile) {
  // ...
}
```

**EDIT: based on the question update**

> For completeness: my application @Configuration class also instantiates the StepScope

When you use `@EnableBatchProcessing`, you don't need to register the step scope manually, the annotation will add it automatically. Here is an excerpt from its [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html):

```
Once you have an @EnableBatchProcessing class in your configuration you will have an instance of StepScope and JobScope so your beans inside steps can have @Scope("step") and @Scope("job") respectively.
```

So in your case, you need to remove the `scope` bean of type `StepScope`.

Comment: I had this before but when I add @Bean I get following error: `The bean 'scopedTarget.importTasksReader', defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource 
[TaskImportJobConfiguration.class], could not be registered. 
A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [TaskImportJobConfiguration.class] 
and overriding is disabled.`

Comment: In this case, re-add this `@Bean` annotation and edit your question with the full stacktrace of the error you have, because this is the correct way of using a step-scoped bean. We can't talk about a Spring (Batch) scope for an object without this object being defined as a bean.

Comment: Thanks for your time already. I've updated the initial question with the info you asked for.

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for your updates. I updated the answer accordingly. If this does not help, please provide a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient manner.

Comment: This did the trick. After all the combinations I tried, apparently I didn't try this combination. Thank you very much for your patience.